# Excel add-in custom functions compatible with existing com Add-in UDF

Tags: office-js, exceljs, custom-functions-excel

I have existing custom function created in Com Add-in. To support MAC and online I am creating a web Add-in. I have included the equivalent add-in in the manifest. but the web add-in does not recognize the custom function created in com add-in when the same workbook opened on browser/mac instead it throws #Name? and displays the namespace used in com add-in.

```
<EquivalentAddins>
 <EquivalentAddin>
  <ProgId>xxx.Office.Formulas</ProgId>
  <Type>COM</Type>
</EquivalentAddin>
```

Custom function used in com Add-in template "=get("data").

Custom function displayed on Browser "=@xxx.Office.Formulas.get("data")"

Answer (score 0):

In browser/mac the equivalent web Add-in will be called instead. The usage is similar with Com Add-in, i.e "=get("data")". You may can refer to [Custom Functions Compatible with Xll UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/make-custom-functions-compatible-with-xll-udf)

Comment: I have gone through this document, but no luck. The equivalent add-in does not identify formula created in com add-in

Comment: Looks like the CF is not installed for Web Add-in.  You may can try to remove the whole EquivalentAddins node and see if the CF can be recognized by Web-Addin without EquivalentAddins node.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the equivalentAddins node from the formula, the CF gets detected and fetches data.